# python class default parameter

Tags: python

I was wondering if someone could explain why these two examples ultimately yield the same result:

```
class Myclass(): 

def __init__ (self, parameter=None)

    if parameter is None: 
        self.parameter = 1.0 
    else: 
        self.parameter = parameter
```

and:

```
class Myclass():

def __init__ (self, parameter=None)

    if parameter: 
        self.parameter = parameter 
    else: 
        self.parameter = 1.0
```

I intuitively understand the first 'if... is None' but I struggle with the second example. Are both ok to use?

I realise this could be quite an easy question hence if anyone could direct me to any reading that would help to understand the difference that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: They don't always return the same result.  Try with sending parameter=0 to see that.

Comment: `None` is *falsy*, so the else branch is taken in the second case when the default value is used. However, there are exceptions.

Comment: Have a look at [Truth value testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

Comment: ... and prefer the first example !

Comment: If you do `MyClass(0.)` do you want `parameter` to be `0.` or `1.`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not equivalent, in the first code snippet, `parameter` will be 1.0 **if and only if** `parameter` is `None`, but in the second one, `parameter` will be 1.0 for any `falsy value`.The following values are all `falsy` in Python:

- None
- False
- zero of any numeric type, for example, 0, 0L, 0.0, 0j.
- any empty sequence, for example, '', (), [].
- any empty mapping, for example, {}.
- instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a **nonzero**() or **len**() method, when that method returns the integer zero or bool value False.

So the first code snippet is more strict. Official docs please refer to:

- Python 2: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing
- Python 3: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Comment: that makes sense, thank you for answering and the links!

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, the condition will only be true if `parameter` is literally `None`.

In the second example, the condition will only be true for truthy values.

A simpler way of showing it would be:

```
def meth1 (parameter):
  return parameter is None

def meth2 (parameter):
  return not(bool(parameter))

print([(meth1(v), meth2(v)) for v in [False, None, 0]])

> [(False, True), (True, True), (False, True)]
```

Comment: could you demonstrate that with a simple example?

Comment: I was outside in the rain, and the water was messing with my touchscreen, so any typing was hard. I also misread the question. Updating now.